# Include filename in output

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I would like to get content from files in a folder (ignoring the header lines, since some file may **ONLY** contain the header). But in the output, I would like to include the filename from which the line is read. So far, I have the following:

`Get-ChildItem | Get-Content | Where { $_ -notlike "HEADER_LINE_TEXT" } | Out-File -FilePath output_text.txt`

I've tried to work with creating a variable in the Where block, `$filename=$_.BaseName`, and using it in the output, but this didn't work.

**EDIT:**

I ended up with the following:

`Get-ChildItem -Path . | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -like "*records.txt"; $fname=$_FullName; } | 
    Get-Content | 
    Select-Object { ($fname + "|" + $_.Trim()) } | 
    Where { $_ -notlike "*HEADER_LINE_TEXT*" } | 
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
    Out-File -FilePath output_text.txt`

This looks lengthy, and can probably be made shorter and clearer. Can someone help with cleaning this up a bit? I'll either post the solution, or vote for a cleaner solution, if one is posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case where it would make it more readable to not make it a one liner at cost of a little additional memory usage.

```
$InputFolder = "C:\example"
$OutputFile = "C:\example\output_text.txt"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | Where-Object { $_.FullName -like "*records.txt"}
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $FilteredContent = Get-Content $File.FullName | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*HEADER_LINE_TEXT*"}
    $Output = $FilteredContent | Foreach-Object { "$($File.FullName)|$($_.Trim())" }
    $Output | Out-File $OutputFile -Append
}
```

If you are going to go oneliner style for brevity, you could cut down on length by using position for parameters and using aliases.

Here are a couple other changes:

- No need for the second semicolon in your first `where` block.
- I think your variable wasn't working because you were missing the period between `$_` and `fullname`.
- `Format-Table` isn't needed because you already have the string you want to output
- You can optimize a little by moving the second `where` earlier so that you don't `trim()` on lines you are just going to filter
- Looks like you want to use `foreach` instead of `select`
- Removed the `+` operator for string concatenation, instead using `$()` to evaluate inside parenthesis

```
gci . | 
    ? { $_.FullName -like "*records.txt"; $fname=$_.FullName } | 
    % { gc $_.FullName } | 
    ? { $_ -notlike "*HEADER_LINE_TEXT*" } | 
    % { "$fname|$($_.Trim())" } | 
    Out-File output_text.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, @BenH. I didn't really mean to keep it as a single line. Your proposed solution in the first block of code worked for me.

Comment: Both approaches work, and have pros/cons. But I would agree that the first approach is what I would use because I prioritize readability and easy modification whenever reasonable. Glad it worked : )